# Mongo Php for checking daterange

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a query like this

```
db.listings.find({ "h_id":  ObjectId("52f1fb19388f5827148b4567"), "data.status":1,"data.startdate":new Date("2014-03-10"),"data.enddate":new Date("2014-03-12") },  {"data.$":1 });
```

Which will return the sub documents which has startdate= 2014-03-10 and enddate 2014-03-12.

Bu when I try to code the same in php-mongo, the array is empty.

I have tried like this

```
$query = array("h_id" => new MongoId($hId),
         "data.status" => 1,
        "data.startdate" => new MongoDate(strtotime("2014-03-10")),
        "data.enddate" => new MongoDate(strtotime("2014-03-12")));


$projection =  array("data.$" => true);

$cursor = $collection->find($query, $projection);
```

Is it possible to check the dates direcly in php-mongo or do we need to use '$lte' or '$gte' for checking dateranges.

Can anyone please help me to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Anyone please help me to fix this?

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem (your example should work in PHP)? If it doesn't work, you should post a sample document .. I would suspect the dates have been stored with a timezone that matches in the shell but doesn't match the timezone you are using in PHP.